# Accessing a static function outside the file

Tags: c, static

Contiki 3.0 declares `setreg()` to be `static` which was not `static` in earlier versions. I need to access function outside the file to perform `setreg(CC2420_MDMCTRL0,0)`.    (https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/dev/cc2420/cc2420.c#L392 )

Is it good to just remove the `static` keyword from the function prototype?
What is the standard practice to deal with such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular code, but if a function is declared `static` it means that it is not visible outside of its [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

I guess that the authors of that software have good reasons to hide that `setreg` function. You should ask them why.

I imagine that they want you to call some *public* functions (like `cc2420_set_cca_threshold`) calling that internal `setreg`. Apparently, most such functions are locking & unlocking something using `GET_LOCK` & `RELEASE_LOCK`.

> Is it good to just remove the static keyword from the function prototype?

No that would be probably very wrong

> What is the standard practice to deal with such cases?

Take many hours to understand that particular software, study its documentation and source code, understand the implicit invariants used by the coders, and follow them.

<sup>(blindly messing with some OS-like code is a sure recipe for disaster; you might perhaps even break your hardware if you do wrong things)</sup>